# Ubuntu heat & fan control on Lenovo

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad, overheating, fan, heat

I tried to use Ubuntu (12.10) on my MacBook Pro 8,2 but it wasnt possible to use because it was always very hot and in fact there wasn't fan control. The fans always turned the same speed and nothing what I installed and tried helped.

Now I want to buy a Lenovo Laptop and I hope there are not that problems.

1. Has all Ubuntu Certified Hardware, in my example the Lenovo Laptops, a good working fan control and heat management?
2. The IBM Thinkpad T41 is not Ubuntu Certified. But is there a correct fan control / heat management?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you have APCI installed?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Certified Hardware pretty much guarantees a fully working machine, including proper fan management. I've never had Linux issues with a certified Lenovo, and if you do, Lenovo will help you solve the problem.

Fan control and heat management is usually support I find in all laptops as long as they are ACPI compliant. And according to [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/IBM_ThinkPad_T41) ArchLinux Wiki entry, the ThinkPad T41 has excellent ACPI support and supports nearly every function relating to it, including fan control and heat management.

That seems to be the least of any of the problems with using that laptop with Ubuntu. However, according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112932/which-distro-should-i-use-on-an-ibm-thinkpad-t41-for-speed) AskUbuntu question, it appears it may not be fast enough for Ubuntu 12.10. I'd recommend sticking with 12.04 or Lubuntu for that one.

Comment: I have a certified Lenovo (Thinkpad t430) but my fan constantly runs, even at times it wouldn't in Windows. Do you have any ideas?